# How to use same two column names in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sql-server

I have two tables which as same column name called id (stores record id). I'm using an inner join on these 2 tables and taking the id column of 2 tables. I'm using this select query in the angularjs `http.get` rest API. When the rest API throws the resultant table which contain 2 column of same name-id, I'm storing this in scope variable.

**The problem is** how can i use the id of one particular table.

consider query is,

```
select t1.id,t2.id 
from table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.product=t1.product_id
```

I am storing the result of rest API in scope variable,
`$scope.details=response.data.platform.record;`

I used these below syntax inside alert box in controller but not working,
`$scope.details.id, $scope.details.t1.id`.

Comment: `select t1.id as t1id,t2.id as t2id from table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.product=t1.product_id` use alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [column alias name](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), will solve your problem:

```
SELECT t1.id AS T1Id, 
       t2.id AS T2Id
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.product = t1.product_id
```

and in your controller, you can use as:

```
$scope.details.T1Id 
$scope.details.T2Id
```